# What is the difference of cores and cors in my node package.json?

Tags: node.js, cors, package.json

In My Nodejs package.json i am able to see "cores": "^0.8.5" and  "cors": "^2.8.4" , what is the difference of Cores and cors ?

Comment: Same as between "wars" and "wares": an "E". `cors` is a library that helps handle Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS). `cores` is apparently something to do with CouchDB. Absolutely nothing remotely similar, except the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CORS** is a NODEJs package for providing a Connect middleware, which is a simple framework to glue together various "middleware" to handle requests. In other words, it is a security relaxation measure that needs to be implemented in some APIs in order to let web browsers access them. By the way, cors stands for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing.

Whereas Cores is a NODEJs which provides CouchDB resources.

Refer to the NPM documentations:

[CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

[CORES](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cores)